# How to make four threads in a class C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, vector

I am having trouble creating four threads in a class each using another member function to print out the contents of each vector. However, I am getting an error `no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list` on those 4 lines when I make the thread. I don't know why it doesn't work if I am trying to use another member function for the thread. Could it be because they are inside a class? How would I fix those 4 errors?

```
class PrintfourVectors
{
private:
    vector<string> one;
    vector<string> two;
    vector<string> three;
    vector<string> four;
public:
    void printOne()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void printTwo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }


    void printThree()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void printFour()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void makeFourThreads()
    {
        thread threadone(printOne);   // error here
        thread threadtwo(printTwo);   // error here
        thread threadthree(printThree); // error here
        thread threadfour(printFour); // error here

        threadone.join();
        threadtwo.join();
        threadthree.join();
        threadfour.join();

    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're calling non-static member functions, and those have a "hidden" first argument that becomes the `this` pointer in the functions. Therefore when creating threads using non-static member function you need to pass the object instance as an argument to the thread function.

Like

```
thread threadone(&PrintfourVectors::printOne, this);
//                                            ^^^^
// Pass pointer to object instance as argument to the thread function
```